# Java Thread Synchronization

Tags: synchronization

Java has two ways to implement **synchronization**. My code gives the correct answer when I use the **synchronized keyword** after the method, but gives me wrong output when I use **synchronized block**. Here is the code which gives me wrong output.
I have used eclipse IDE to compile and run this code.

```
package synchronizedPackage;

public class Synch1 {

public class callMe {

    void call(String msg)
    {
        System.out.print("[ "+msg);

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

public class caller implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    callMe target;
    String msg;

    public caller(callMe targ, String msg)
    {
        target = targ;
        this.msg = msg;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(target)
        {
            target.call(msg);
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Synch1 s = new Synch1();
    callMe target = s.new callMe();
    caller ob1 = s.new caller(target, "Hello");
    caller ob2 = s.new caller(target, "Synchronized");
    caller ob3 = s.new caller(target, "world");

    try{
        ob1.t.join();
        ob2.t.join();
        ob3.t.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code sample provided by you And it is working fine. As you are working with threads 1 thing to remember the **threads can be run in any order** and it is not in out control, i.e., we can not expect the same output each time. For each run you may get same output or may not. It is designed in java like that. Is that the this you are expecting or anything else.